# A "philanthropic" businessman

Tags: economy, infrastructure

My story is set in the modern world.  A businessman sets up shop in a developing nation, using wealth he obtained from business in his own country to run a profitable business in the developing country.  By so doing, he increases the infrastructure of the country, and aggressively expands his business to expand the infrastructure.  He claims that the infrastructure expansion benefits the developing country, and calls himself a philanthropist.

First; could this actually work, economically?  Certainly, it would be very difficult if it even is possible, but what would the specific challenges be?  Transporting the material for the initial infrastructure?  Getting qualified workers?

Second; how fast could this fellow expand his business, and thus pay for further infrastructure development?

Third; what would the natives' response be?  I assume they wouldn't be very happy, but are there historical examples that could provide context?

Comment: It is usually called outsourcing, and works very well.

Comment: This is the standard paradigm for international business working in developing countries. Possible? It happens all the time. It works economically by fleecing the developing country. The "natives" usually aren't happy about it. That's why they call it foreign exploitation" or if they're bit politically savvy "neo-colonialism". For historical examples, look at almost any developing country.

Comment: @a4android: Should more accurately be called "biting the hand that feeds you", but that's human nature for you. "If you pick up a starving dog and make him prosperous he will not bite you. This is the principal difference between a dog and a man." - Mark Twain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear where the world-building element is in this, as this describes basically what already exists, and a phenomenon that drove the history of Western colonialism. This man might want to call himself a philanthropist, but one person's philanthropist is another's robber baron - it's an empty term.

Chosen purely at random, here's a historical example, the [United Fruit Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Fruit_Company). In any of these cases there's an obvious confluence of interests between such companies and the ruling élites of the country. The élites want the lucrative tax income, bribes, and infrastructure projects, and in exchange the company will want state power to be used to enforce monopolies and suppress the rights of workers to keep their costs down.

So to answer your questions:

1) Not difficult at all. The entire structure of global capitalism is designed to facilitate exactly this.

2) As fast as he wants. But you have to question what infrastructure it will be that he will build. The railways that exist in developing countries for example tend to be built to optimise the extraction of resources. So, they'll be built to link fruit plantations, diamond mines, etc. to the country's seaports. There's very little incentive to build city-to-city railways, by contrast, and it's this infrastructure which allows citizens in a country to trade *with each other* that actually helps drive development.

3) See basically any anti-colonial struggle. The philanthropist will press the government to do their bit to keep his workers in order, so he can keep wages down and his business competitive. This leads to right wing death squads, and to a communist resistance.